# Is it possible to change the result attribute of a wcf webservice?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, soap, methods

I have a problem with the response method of the Soap server.
It is a .net WCF webservice

The following code:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract()]
    List<DealerLead> GetDealerLeads(List<DealerLeadsRequest> accountnummerString);
}
```

Will return this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetDealerLeadsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetDealerLeadsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SoapTest"     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

But how can i change it to this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
  <GetDealerLeadsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <AOtherMethodName xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SoapTest" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So only the method result name must be changed, is this possible with WCF?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control the name of the SOAP operation, you can use

```
[OperationContract(Name = "AOtherMethodName")]
```

If you really want to control the format of the message on the wire, you'll need to define a [message contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx)

Comment: Ok, with the Name param i can change the responce attribute but it it changed the method call too and it is not AOtherMethodName but AOtherMethodNameResult is it possible without the Result text in the attribute?

Comment: Same problem, any way to do it?